# How to select the data from datatable which not in an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable, ienumerable

I have a DataTable `dbcrs` and I want to get only the data which is **not** in the following enumerable:

```
IEnumerable<Crs> res
```

**Note :**  the key in both is `id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

```
var result = dbcrs.Where(item => res.FirstOrDefault(resItem => resItem.Id == item.Id) == null);
```

Comment: `dbcrs.Where(item => res.FirstOrDefault(resItem => resItem.Id.TrimEnd() == item.[0].ToString().TrimEnd()) == null);`

Answer (score 1):

First you need to use `AsEnumerable()` in order to query against the DataTable's Rows collection, then use `!Contains` as not in like this:

```
var query = from r in dbcrs.AsEnumerable()
        where !( from s in res select r.Id)
               .Contains(r.Id)
        select r;
```

Answer (score 1):

An example of doing this with Except and IEquatable<>

A benefit of this way is that you can define what you mean by "Equals", so that two lists which may have the same ID's but are NOT equal can still be used.

e.g. You get data from two tables, so the Id's can repeat but some other properties define if they are actually equal.

```
class Crs:IEquatable<Crs>
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }

            public bool Equals(Crs other)
            {
                if (Object.ReferenceEquals(other, null)) 
                    return false;

                if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, other)) 
                    return true;

                return Id.Equals(other.Id) && Description.Equals(other.Description);
            }

            public override int GetHashCode()
            {
                int hashId = Id.GetHashCode();
                int hashDescription = Description == null ? 0 : Description.GetHashCode();
                return hashId ^ hashDescription;
            }

        }

        internal static void RunMe()
        {
            var dataTable = new List<Crs>(){
                new Crs{Id=1, Description="First"},
                new Crs{Id=2, Description="Second"},
                new Crs{Id=5, Description="Fifth"}
            };

            var enumerable = new List<Crs>(){
                new Crs{Id=2, Description="Second"},
                new Crs{Id=4, Description="Fourth"}
            };

            var distinct = dataTable.Except(enumerable);

            distinct.ToList().ForEach(d => Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", d.Id, d.Description));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[]
        {
            new DataColumn("Id", typeof(System.Int32)),
            new DataColumn("Name", typeof(System.String))

        });

        dt.Rows.Add (new Object[]{1,"Test"});
        dt.Rows.Add(new Object[] {2, "Test" });



        var l = new Int32[] {  2, 4 };


        var l1 = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(p1 => Array.IndexOf(l, p1.Field<Int32>(0))<0).CopyToDataTable();
```

This would return us one row because in Datatable and array both have one value in common that's 2 only. so out put will be

2,  Test